# Using cut on vector of objects of class Date

Tags: r, date, cut

Since the default argument `right` in `cut` is by default set to `TRUE` I would have expected to get exactly the same results by the two following `cut` comments. Why is this not the case?

```
> breaks <- as.Date(c("2016-02-05", "2016-02-12", "2016-02-19"))
> d <- as.Date("2016-02-12")
> cut(d, breaks, right=TRUE)
[1] 2016-02-05
Levels: 2016-02-05 2016-02-12
> cut(d, breaks)
[1] 2016-02-12
Levels: 2016-02-05 2016-02-12
```

However, when I first convert the `Date` objects into numeric values I obtain the same results:

```
> breaks <- as.numeric(as.Date(c("2016-02-05", "2016-02-12", "2016-02-19")))
> d <- as.numeric(as.Date("2016-02-12"))
> cut(d, breaks, right=TRUE)
[1] (16836,16843]
Levels: (16836,16843] (16843,16850]
> cut(d, breaks)
[1] (16836,16843]
Levels: (16836,16843] (16843,16850]
```

Isn't this counterintuitive?

Comment: "Since the default argument `right` in `cut` is by default set to `TRUE`". Yes, for `cut.default`. But see `?cut.Date` which is the method applied when `x` is of class `Date`: default is `right = FALSE`. It also says in Details: "Note that the default for `right` differs from the default method [i.e. `cut.default`]"

Comment: Many thanks for clarification. I was not aware of that. Next time I will check the help page more carefully.